# Create a new column in a dataframe which adds values with change corresponding to another column

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

Create new column that assigns values based on if the values of another column change or not.

So I have the following dataframe:

[image]

And I want to add a new column named "trip" that starts with value 1 and sums 1 each time the column "orientation" changes values, so that the final dataframe would look like this:

[image]

How can I do that in python ?

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
df['trip'] = df['orientation'].ne(df['orientation'].shift()).cumsum()
```